# Dividir array e ordenar

Tags: php, array

Possuo um array da seguinte forma:

```
'Ato001_1981',
'Ato002_1980',
'Ato003_1982',
'Ato003_1983',
'Ato004_1982',
'Ato013_1981',
'Ato013_1982',
'Ato013_1988',
'Ato031_1982',
'Ato032_1979',
'Ato039_1988',
'Ato060_1987',
'Ato065_1988',
'Ato066_1988',
'Ato067_1988',
'Ato076_1987',
'Ato077_1988',
'Ato078_1988',
'Ato095_1987',
'Ato137_1987',
'Ato144_1987'
```

Gostaria de quebrar cada linha do array para pegar o nome e o ano e posteriormente ordenar como no texto abaixo:

```
Ano     Tipo
1988    Ato078
1988    Ato077
1988    Ato067
1988    Ato066
1988    Ato065
1988    Ato039
1988    Ato013
1987    Ato144
1987    Ato137
1987    Ato095
1987    Ato076
1987    Ato060
1983    Ato003
1982    Ato031
1982    Ato013
1982    Ato004
1982    Ato003
1981    Ato013
1981    Ato001
1980    Ato002
1979    Ato032
```

tentei o código abaixo, mas sem sucesso:

```
$new = array();
foreach($texto as $item):
    $valor = explode('_', $item);
    $new['ano'] = $valor[1];
    $new['tipo'] = $valor[0];    
    print_r($new);    
endforeach;
```

Comment: O problema é como ordenar baseado em `ano` e do maior para o menor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De maneira mais elegante possível, vamos à solução:

O seu array é o seguinte:

```
$dados = array(
    'Ato001_1981',
    'Ato002_1980',
    'Ato003_1982',
    'Ato003_1983',
    'Ato004_1982',
    'Ato013_1981',
    'Ato013_1982',
    'Ato013_1988',
    'Ato031_1982',
    'Ato032_1979',
    'Ato039_1988',
    'Ato060_1987',
    'Ato065_1988',
    'Ato066_1988',
    'Ato067_1988',
    'Ato076_1987',
    'Ato077_1988',
    'Ato078_1988',
    'Ato095_1987',
    'Ato137_1987',
    'Ato144_1987'
);
```

Primeiro vamos transformar esse `array`. Creio que a função mais adequada pra isso é utilizando `array_map`, por conta de proteção do escopo da variável e de funcionalidade própria para geração de arrays baseado em outros.

```
$array = array_map(function ($value){
    return explode('_', $value);
}, $dados);
```

Posterioremente utilizaremos `usort`, que compara os valores do `array`, através de um callback, a fim de ordená-lo.

```
usort($array, function ($v1, $v2)
{
    $diff = $v2[1] - $v1[1];

    if ($diff) return $diff;

    return strcmp($v2[0], $v1[0]);

});
```

E por fim, temos o `array` - obtido com `var_export`.

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ato078',
    1 => '1988',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ato077',
    1 => '1988',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ato067',
    1 => '1988',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ato066',
    1 => '1988',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ato065',
    1 => '1988',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ato039',
    1 => '1988',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ato013',
    1 => '1988',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ato144',
    1 => '1987',
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ato137',
    1 => '1987',
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ato095',
    1 => '1987',
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ato076',
    1 => '1987',
  ),
  11 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ato060',
    1 => '1987',
  ),
  12 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ato003',
    1 => '1983',
  ),
  13 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ato031',
    1 => '1982',
  ),
  14 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ato013',
    1 => '1982',
  ),
  15 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ato004',
    1 => '1982',
  ),
  16 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ato003',
    1 => '1982',
  ),
  17 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ato013',
    1 => '1981',
  ),
  18 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ato001',
    1 => '1981',
  ),
  19 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ato002',
    1 => '1980',
  ),
  20 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Ato032',
    1 => '1979',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Obrigado. funcionou da forma que eu estava precisando

Answer (score 2):

```
$texto = array(
    'Ato001_1981',
    'Ato002_1980',
    'Ato003_1982',
    'Ato003_1983',
    'Ato004_1982',
    'Ato013_1981',
    'Ato013_1982',
    'Ato013_1988',
    'Ato031_1982',
    'Ato032_1979',
    'Ato039_1988',
    'Ato060_1987',
    'Ato065_1988',
    'Ato066_1988',
    'Ato067_1988',
    'Ato076_1987',
    'Ato077_1988',
    'Ato078_1988',
    'Ato095_1987',
    'Ato137_1987',
    'Ato144_1987'
);

$new = array();
foreach($texto as $item):
    $valor = explode('_', $item);
    $new = ['ano' => $valor[1], 'tipo' => $valor[0]];

    echo $new['ano'] . '  ' . $new['tipo'] . '<br />';
endforeach;
```

Aqui funcionou assim.

Comment: Não entendi como vc ordenou o array.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeirtamente

Comment: OOG @rray (Orientação orientada a gambiarra)

Answer (score 1):

A forma menos ruim de ordernar o array baseado na chave é utilizar [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return $a["ano"] < $b["ano"];
}


$texto = ['Ato001_1981','Ato002_1980','Ato003_1982','Ato003_1983','Ato004_1982','Ato013_1981'];

$new = array();
$index  = 0;
foreach($texto as $item){
    $valor = explode('_', $item);
    $new[$index]['tipo'] = $valor[0];
    $new[$index]['ano'] = $valor[1];
    $index++;
}

usort($new, "cmp");

echo '<pre>';
print_r($new);
```

Refêrencia: [SOen - Sort php multidimensional array by sub-value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4508145/1342547)

Comment: Eu consigui o resultado similar mas no seu caso esta acontecendo a mesma coisa que o meu, o `array` esta agrupando itens iguais, como podemos fazer para que ele não agrupe?

Comment: @RafaelAcioly, agrupando? usei `$index` para definir chaves que não se repitam, se vc basear so no ano ai ele sobrescreve a chave toda vez.

Comment: O resultado que tive com seu metodo agrupo aqui, só apareceram 5 arrays. o resultado aqui aqui; http://pastebin.com/dyHu3Jc3

Comment: Aqui tem 20 elementos, no exemplo da resposta só coloquei 5 elementos. @RafaelAcioly. O erro era que a ordem estava `asc` e deveria ser `desc` isso acertei.